# Where does bundler store gems?

Tags: ruby, rubygems, rvm, bundler, gemset

I know that when using `gem install`, the gem will be stored under /home/username/.rvm/gems/, under which gemset the gem was installed.

But if I use Bundler and specify the gem in the Gemfile, when I run bundle install, where will those gems be stored? And what if I already installed the gem using `gem install`, if I run bundle install, will it use the previous gem installed using `gem install`?

Comment: `bundle show <gemname>`

Comment: Bundler now says "[DEPRECATED] use `bundle info <gemname>` instead of `bundle show <gemname>`".

Answer (score 67, accepted):

It depends. In the usual development setup they are installed where they would be when you install a gem "normally" (by running `gem install foo`) and bundler won't reinstall gems that are already there. This location depends on how rubygems itself is configured.

If you run bundle install with the `--deployment` option then the gems will be installed in a location unique to your app (you can pass this as a separate option but it defaults to vendor/bundle)

You can also run `bundle package` to store all the .gem files your app uses in `vendor/cache`. Running `bundle install` will prefer gems in vendor/cache to gems in other locations.

Comment: You can also specify the installation path as a parameter to [bundle install](http://gembundler.com/v1.2/bundle_install.html): `$ bundle install --path vendor/bundle`

Comment: I didn't understand the answer, so what is the default installation path for bundle install? If it's used in development.

Comment: in development, it will install them in the same place as just doing `gem install` would (which depends on GEM_HOME, GEM_PATH etc)

Comment: So, by default it will install all gems in a system-wide (as opposed to project-specific) location?

Comment: @David it could be system wide or a user specific location, depending on rubygems configuration.

Answer (score 93):

If you want to find out where a particular gem is stored you can run `bundle info <gem-name>`. For example:

```
user@host$ bundle info rake
/var/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.4.2
```

For older versions of rake, the command could be `bundle show <gem_name>.`

Comment: Does this imply that all gems are just installed on your ruby?

Comment: Note that `bundle show GEM` is deprecated in favor of `bundle info GEM`

Answer (score 10):

I use `bundle config path` to see where gems are stored.

Answer (score 3):

Here `/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/` and here: `/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/bundler/gems/`.

Comment: I'd imagine this only applies to certain operating systems

Comment: Do you know how bundler decides which gems go in which directory?

Answer (score 2):

Note that gems are also installed into the `bundle` folder within your "Gem Path" (see: `bundle env`). This happens, for example, with gems installed from `git`:

```
gem 'my-gem', git: "https://github.com/x/y.git"
```

I assume this is so that custom installations don't conflict with installations from a gem server.