# installed gem in folder instead of root

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, sass

I'm fairly new to sass and compass and was a bit confused about installing the gem for zurb-foundation. I eventually managed to install it (quite simply in the end) but had navigated to the project folder on my desktop. Does this mean that the gem is installed in the project folder and not the root? Or does it matter? If so, how can I move it?

Please pardon my complete ignorance.

Comment: How exactly did you install it? Did you do `gem install zurb-foundation` or did you add `zurb-foundation` to your `Gemfile` and do `bundle install`?

Comment: I just did `sudo gem install zurb-foundation` from terminal but I was in a project folder instead of root

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It does not matter, they are installed on your machine and are generally available. If, for some reason, you need to make sure they are specially for your application, you need to use the `bundle install --development` option. Please see this thread [Where does bundler store gems?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11635042/where-does-bundler-store-gems)

Comment: Thanks for that. Still having a bit of a problem: when I run `compass create project-name -r zurb-foundation --using foundation` I get -bash: compass: command not found. I have compass installed (with Codekit) so maybe its the path?

Comment: Yes, that sounds like a path issue

Comment: I just reinstalled it and that fixed it, not sure if that was a good idea but I was getting impatient.