# Digest::Digest is deprecated; use Digest

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, fog

I am getting the following error

```
Digest::Digest is deprecated; use Digest
```

when i try to boot my rails server. I tried to search my source code for `Digest::Digest` but i am not using it anywhere.  any idea how to solve that?

Only place i am using is

```
<% digest = OpenSSL::Digest.new('sha1') %>

@alias = Digest::MD5.hexdigest(phone)
```

Comment: @AndreyDeineko can you share the link? is it this - https://rubygems.org/gems/ackr/versions/0.2.4

Comment: added few more options :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is most likely used by one of the gems your app is dependent on.

install (unless already installed) [ack tool](http://beyondgrep.com/) and run the following command:

```
# of course, the path to your gems will be different
ack Digest::Digest /Users/username/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.1/gems/
```

It will show you whether any of the gems use it, and if yes - will show you the source code lines.

But basically there is not much you can do:

1. Check, whether this gem has a newer version, which solves the deprecation warning
2. Write a patch to the gem, which solves the warning and use patched verions (not cool idea IMO)
3. Live with warning until gem maintainers work on that
4. You can silence the depreciation warnings altogether with `ActiveSupport::Deprecation.silenced = true` (not cool idea as well IMO). There is also a way to silence specific warning, as **@max** says in comments):

   ```
   silenced = [
     /Digest::Digest is deprecated; use Digest/,
     /some other warning/,
   ]

   silenced_expr = Regexp.new(silenced.join('|'))

   ActiveSupport::Deprecation.behavior = lambda do |msg, stack|
     unless msg =~ silenced_expr
       ActiveSupport::Deprecation::DEFAULT_BEHAVIORS[:stderr].call(msg, stack)
     end
   end
   ```
5. Do not use this gem

Comment: and i am using the latest versions :(

Comment: @HarshaMV then as I say, you either wait until gem maintainers update it or live with the warning message..

Comment: @HarshaMV no probs :)

Comment: You can silence the depreciation notices with `ActiveSupport::Deprecation.silenced = true` or by `ActiveSupport::Deprecation.silenced do; end`.

Comment: @max totally forgot about this one, will edit the answer

Comment: I think there is some way to filter out specific notices as well but can't remember it at the moment.

Comment: I wasn't aware of any remaining `Digest::Digest` in fog, happy to patch them but some initial searching wasn't turning any up on the master repo.

Comment: You can use `bundle show rake` to find the folder where your gems are. Reference: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32638896/72176.