# DEPRECATION WARNING: alias_method_chain is deprecated

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, ruby-on-rails-5

I upgraded the project to Rails 5. When I run `rspec` I get a warning

```
DEPRECATION WARNING: alias_method_chain is deprecated. Please, use Module#prepend instead. 
From module, you can access the original method using super. 
(called from <top (required)> at /home/alex/projects/myproject/config/application.rb:13)
```

The failing line in application.rb is:

```
Bundler.require(*Rails.groups)
```

How do I find out what is causing this deprecation warning and how to get rid of the error?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Install (unless already installed) [ack](http://beyondgrep.com/install/) and run in the terminal:

```
ack alias_method_chain /Users/username/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.1/gems/
```

It will indicate all places where `alias_method_chain` is used (files and code lines).

99% chance it is used in some of your gems.

See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40082768/digestdigest-is-deprecated-use-digest/40082854#40082854) for a list of things you can do about it.

Comment: @AlexanderShmatko make sure to provide correct path to your current gems directory :)

Comment: If anyone wants to install `ack` mentioned above through `CPAN`, here's a great tutorial for a newbie https://egoleo.wordpress.com/2008/05/19/how-to-install-perl-modules-through-cpan-on-ubuntu-hardy-server/

Comment: or use `ag` instead of `ack` - same thing, but faster

Answer (score 7):

In OSX, you can use:

```
grep -Ir alias_method_chain `bundle show rails`/..
```

And that will list all of the gems that use `alias_method_chain`

Answer (score 3):

If the Gemfile is too large I would recommend to use [the_silver_searcher](https://github.com/ggreer/the_silver_searcher) to search for deprecated alias_method_chain because it is faster

```
ag alias_method_chain /path/to/gemset
```

I have `gepgems` bash helper function to not type /path/to/gemset every time

```
grepgems alias_method_chain
```

To use it add the following function to your .bash_profile (or somewhere else in the dotfiles you like)

```
function grepgems() {
  ag $1 $GEM_HOME"/gems"
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Solution for docker :

> docker exec -it [CONTAINER_NAME] /bin/bash
>
> apt-get install silversearcher-ag
>
> ag alias_method_chain $GEM_HOME"/gems"