# Cloned a repo, but running into Invalid option key: page_cache_directory= (RuntimeError)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, publify

I cloned a Ruby project called Publify (an open-source blogging platform.) However, when I run rails server, I get the following error (I have copy-pasted the info below the image) > [image]

```
DEPRECATION WARNING: alias_method_chain is deprecated. Please, use Module#prepend instead. From module, you can access the original method using super. (called from <class:Simple> at /home/ubuntu/workspace/publify-master/lib/i18n_interpolation_deprecation.rb:24)
=> Booting Thin
=> Rails 5.0.3 application starting in development on http://0.0.0.0:8080
=> Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
Exiting
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/actionpack-5.0.3/lib/action_controller/railtie.rb:60:in `block (3 levels) in <class:Railtie>': Invalid option key: page_cache_directory= (RuntimeError)
```

And then a slew of "From:" statements (as seen in the image.)

My open repo is here, if you would like to take a look: https://gitlab.com/AvBloom98/publify. I did some work to update the gems and such, because they were failing before, thus it is not 1-to-1 with the original Publify Github (found here: https://github.com/publify/publify)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [DEPRECATION WARNING: alias\_method\_chain is deprecated](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40173651/deprecation-warning-alias-method-chain-is-deprecated)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Publify gem is setting up page caching directory in its [configuration](https://gitlab.com/AvBloom98/publify/blob/master/config/application.rb#L16) but **page caching has been deprecated and [removed from Rails 4](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/caching_with_rails.html#page-caching)**.

However, you can put page caching support back by adding **[actionpack-page_caching gem](https://github.com/rails/actionpack-page_caching)** into the project, as documented in the [Rails guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/caching_with_rails.html#page-caching). From [this issue](https://github.com/rails/actionpack-page_caching/pull/41) I assume the gem will run nicely in Rails 5, too.