# what are the URLs ruby gem tries to reach to install gems

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I need to install ruby, gem, Ruby on Rails and some other gems in a system which has no access to internet as of now. However, I will be given access for few really required urls for few days. I need to raise a firewall requests for those URLs. Please help with the list of urls.

Comment: You can download the gems and install them specifying the directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[RubyGems.org](http://rubygems.org) is the Ruby community’s gem hosting service.

If a gem can be installed using 'gem install' command that means the gem is available on RubyGems.org. Almost all the useful gems are available here.

In case you want some specific gem that isn't published on RubyGems.org, then you have to whitelist the URL to github repository of that particular gem.

For example a gem 'xyz' if not available at RubyGems.org then whitelist

`https://github.com/user_name/xyz.git` for HTTPS

OR

```
git@github.com:user_name/xyz.git
```

for SSH.

For Ruby, Rails and dependencies installation you need to use these urls:

[ruby-lang.org](http://ruby-lang.org) => if you plan to install ruby using source

`rvm.io` => to install using rvm or better option is to use rbenv.

`nodesource.com` => for installing node.js

and rest depends on your OS. If using debian or Ubuntu you have to whitelist:

`packages.debian.org` and `packages.ubuntu.com`

Most of the packages/gems/dependencies can be installed if you get SSH access to github.com. Or you can try installing the required packages to a system with full internet access and then exporting them to the desired system.

You can use Http proxies if the people behind Firewall aren't smart enough. Or VPN is the only way out as suggested by [#coreyward](https://stackoverflow.com/users/203130/coreyward)

Comment: Note: he also needs to install Ruby and all of its dependencies as well, which depends on the system/OS he's on. Build tools? Package manager?

Comment: I am on Linux OS.

Comment: What variant of Linux? if Ubuntu/debian I have given the url for packages. Note: You can get your Linux distribution name,version etc. details by typing `cat /etc/*-release` in the shell/terminal.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than trying to whitelist individual domains (or worse, documents/pages/urls) you could use a VPN or HTTP proxy and whitelist it. This would allow you to fetch necessary files, updates, gems, etc. without identifying them in advance.

Answer (score 0):

A lot of the gems you can find [here](https://rubygems.org/). However, you can have gems  hosted locally to an organization or you can also install them from their github repo.

However, once you install the gems, they are stored locally in your system and you can access the gems from there without an internet connection.
When you do a bundle install, first your local gems are searched (unless specified otherwise) for the gem and if it does not find there it looks for it in the remote location.
 Check out this answer to know where the gems are usually stored locally. [Where does bundler store gems?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11635042/where-does-bundler-store-gems)